# JSF Datatable why style changes after button click?

Tags: css, jsf, datatable, openfaces

I have a `xhtml` page with two tables that are set css style:

```
<o:dataTable id="productTable" value="#{produkty.produkty}" var="p"
                rowKey="#{p.product.id}" pageSize="10" styleClass="dataTable"
                style="line-height: 15px; font-size: 12px; table-layout: fixed;">
                <o:columnResizing resizeHandleWidth="10px" minColWidth="50px" />
                <o:multipleRowSelection rowDatas="#{produkty.SProdukty}"
                    style="background: #a4aec5; color: white;" mouseSupport="false"
                    keyboardSupport="false" />

                <!-- OPIS -->

                <o:column header="Opis" id="opisCol1"
                    sortingExpression="#{p.product.opis}"
                    style="text-align: left; padding-right: 5px; padding-left: 5px; ">
                    <f:facet name="subHeader">
                        <o:inputTextFilter />
                    </f:facet>
                    <!-- <h:outputText value="#{p.product.opis}" /> -->
                    <o:hintLabel value="#{p.product.opis}" hintTimeout="0"
                        style="width: 350px; margin-right: 10px; color: black; border-color: red;" />
                </o:column>
            </o:dataTable>
```

the style used in `<o:hintLabel>` and `<o:dataTable>` tags set only when I press a button:

addBean method looks like this:

```
public void addBean() {
  add();
  produktyP.chainReaction(this);
}
```

which has nothing in common with the table, but it's reloading page, why onle when i press this button css styles set? In addition, I will say that the site is in  tag. I use OpenFaces lib.

`index.xhtml` source:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:o="http://openfaces.org/">
<h:head>
    <title>PIR Kreator Ofert</title>
    <script src="/WEB-INF/resources/script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/style.css" type="text/css"/>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:form id="form">
        <h:panelGrid columns="2">
            <h:outputLink value="index.xhtml"><h:graphicImage id="logo" alt="pir logo" url="/images/logo.png"/></h:outputLink>
            <h1>Kreator Ofert</h1>
        </h:panelGrid>
        <o:tabbedPane>
            <o:subPanel caption="Nagłówek">

                <ui:include src="index_core/naglowek.xhtml" />

            </o:subPanel>
            <o:subPanel caption="Produkty">

                <ui:include src="index_core/produkty.xhtml" />

            </o:subPanel>

        </o:tabbedPane>
        <h:panelGrid columns="2">
            Sortowanie Elementów:
            <o:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{pdf.sortContent}" />
        </h:panelGrid>
        <h:panelGrid columns="5">
        Nazwa pliku:
            <o:inputText value="#{pdf.fileName}" />
            <o:commandButton id="printButton" value="Drukuj"
                actionListener="#{pdf.printt}" />
            <o:commandButton id="initializePDFButton" value="Reset"
                action="#{pdf.initPDF}" />
            <o:commandLink value="Download PDF" action="#{pdf.downloadPDF}"
                target="_blank" />
        </h:panelGrid>
        <!-- AJAX -->

        <ui:include src="ajax_core/ajax.xhtml" />

    </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

`produkty.xhtml` source:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:o="http://openfaces.org/">

    <h:panelGrid columns="2">
        <h:panelGroup layout="block" id="produktMenu">
            <o:dataTable id="productTable" value="#{produkty.produkty}" var="p"
                rowKey="#{p.product.id}" pageSize="10" styleClass="dataTable"
                >
                <o:columnResizing resizeHandleWidth="10px" minColWidth="50px" />
                <o:multipleRowSelection rowDatas="#{produkty.SProdukty}"
                    style="background: #a4aec5; color: white;" mouseSupport="false"
                    keyboardSupport="false" />

                <o:columnReordering />
                <f:facet name="columnMenu">
                    <o:columnMenu />
                </f:facet>
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <h:outputText value="Tabela Produktów" />
                </f:facet>
                <!-- SELECTION -->
                <o:selectionColumn sortable="true" header="Selection"
                    style="width: 5%;" onclick="O$('form:addProduct').run()">
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <o:selectAllCheckbox style="width: 10px;" />
                    </f:facet>
                </o:selectionColumn>

                <!-- KATEGORIA -->

                <o:column header="Kategoria"
                    sortingExpression="#{p.product.kategoria}">
                    <f:facet name="subHeader">
                        <o:dropDownFieldFilter maxlength="4" customValueAllowed="false"
                            style="width: 40px;" />
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{p.product.kategoria}" />
                </o:column>

                <!-- ILOSC -->

                <o:column header="Ilość">
                    <o:spinner id="ilosc" value="#{p.ilosc}" minValue="1"
                        maxValue="100" onclick="O$('form:addProduct').run()"/>
                </o:column>

                <!-- SYMBOL -->

                <o:column header="Symbol" id="symbolCol1"
                    sortingExpression="#{p.product.symbol}" style="width: 100px">
                    <f:facet name="subHeader">
                        <o:inputTextFilter />
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{p.product.symbol}" />
                </o:column>

                <!-- OPIS -->

                <o:column header="Opis" id="opisCol1"
                    sortingExpression="#{p.product.opis}"
                    style="text-align: left; padding-right: 5px; padding-left: 5px; ">
                    <f:facet name="subHeader">
                        <o:inputTextFilter />
                    </f:facet>
                    <!-- <h:outputText value="#{p.product.opis}" /> -->
                    <o:hintLabel value="#{p.product.opis}" hintTimeout="0"
                        style="width: 350px; margin-right: 10px; color: black; border-color: red;" />
                </o:column>

                <!-- CENA -->

                <o:column header="Cena" id="cenaCol1"
                    sortingExpression="#{p.product.cena}" style="width: 55px;">
                    <h:outputText value="#{p.product.cena}€" />
                </o:column>

                <!-- PAGINATOR -->

                <f:facet name="below">
                    <o:dataTablePaginator id="paginator" firstText="Pierwsza"
                        lastText="Ostatnia" nextText="Następna" previousText="Poprzednia"
                        pageNumberPrefix="Strona" pageCountPreposition="z" />
                </f:facet>
                <f:facet name="footer">
                    <o:commandButton value="Odśwież" type="button"
                        onclick="O$('form:addProduct').run()" />
                </f:facet>
            </o:dataTable>
        </h:panelGroup>
    </h:panelGrid>

</ui:composition>
```

I use DOCTYPE on both pages, because when only index.xhtml has it, Tomcat gives me:

`HTTP Status 500 - /index.xhtml @28,51 <ui:include src="index_core/produkty.xhtml"> Invalid path : index_core/produkty.xhtml`

another thing, when I want to add css file by `<h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="style.css"  />` or `<link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/style.css" type="text/css"/>` tomcat gives me `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/jsp/jstl/core/Config` exception, I add jstl.jar lib to `Tomcat/lib` and nothing helps.

It works on IE olny, why?

Comment: Do you have `<!DOCTYPE` definition at the top of page?

Comment: yes, even twice in <ui:composite> and root page `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">`

Comment: You can leave it just in root page. Try with that, it even may be the cause.

Comment: when I delete it, `<ui:include>` tag does not find this page, so it must be there :/

Comment: You are saying some strange things , how ui:include is related to DOCTYPE .Can you post both your xhtmls ?

Comment: I edited post, please check it.

Comment: Remove `<?xml` from `index.xhtml` and try than.

Comment: it does not help, I tried already